# Resolving state in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to get some content data to my controller:

```
state('admin.businesses.employees.all', {
    resolve: {
        executorsListTitle: 'All employees',
        executorsEmptyListMessage: 'Add the first employee'
    },
    url: '/all',
    controller: 'ExecutorsController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/admin/executors/index.html'
})
```

And a controller code:

```
module.controller(
    'ExecutorsController', 
     [
      '$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', 
      '$stateParams', '$modal', 'executorsListTitle', 
      'executorsEmptyListMessage', 'Executor', 
      function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $modal, executorsListTitle, executorsEmptyListMessage, Executor) {
          // Some code
      }
 )
```

But when I try to get into this state I can't do it - click by button makes nothing; if I remove resolve from state description it works good. What I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resolve of the state machine expects a key and a factory. The [doc states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve):

> - key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
> - factory - {string|function}

And when you provide a string to the factory:

> If string, then it is an alias for a service.

If you want to return a string, you can do the following:

```
state('admin.businesses.employees.all', {
    resolve: {
        executorsListTitle: function() {
             return 'All employees';
        },
        executorsEmptyListMessage: function() {
             return 'Add the first employee';
        },
    },
    url: '/all',
    controller: 'ExecutorsController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/admin/executors/index.html'
})
```

If you are using static data (the strings you are resolving to), you can also use the custom data property:

```
state('admin.businesses.employees.all', {
    data: {
        executorsListTitle: 'All employees',
        executorsEmptyListMessage: 'Add the first employee'
    },
    url: '/all',
    controller: 'ExecutorsController',
    templateUrl: 'templates/admin/executors/index.html'
})
```

If you use this method, in the controller you can access the data like this:

```
$state.current.data.executorsListTitle
```

You can use strings directly with this method. [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects) is the doc for the custom data property.